# Save an object and a nested object with only one Repository save request

Tags: spring, nested, save, repository, cascade

I'm trying to save an object and a nested object with only one JpaRepository request.
So I'm using the save method of parent object's repository.
There are my entities:

**Parent**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "race")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Race {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected int id;

private String name;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "race")
private List<Stage> stages;

// some others attributes

}
```

**Nested**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "stage")
@NoArgsConstructor 
public class Stage {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected int id;

String traceName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "race_id", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "stage_fk_race"))
private Race race;

//some other attributes

}
```

I'm using swagger to try my saving. This is my query's body :

```
{
  "name": "Trail du Clair de Lune",
  "stages": [
    {
      "traceName": "trail_8km.gpx",
    }
  ]
}
```

My controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/race", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class RaceController {

private final RaceService raceService;

@Autowired
public RaceController(RaceService raceService) {
    this.raceService = raceService;
}

@PostMapping(value = "save")
public Race save(@RequestBody Race race) {
    System.out.println(race.toString());
    return raceService.save(race);
}

@GetMapping(path = "/{id}")
public Race getOne(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    Optional<Race> byId = raceService.findById(id);

    if(byId.isPresent()) {
        return byId.get();
    } else return null;
    }
}
```

My service :

```
@Service
public class RaceServiceImpl implements RaceService {

private RaceRepository raceRepository;

@Autowired
public RaceServiceImpl(RaceRepository raceRepository) {
    this.raceRepository = raceRepository;
}

@Override
public Race save(Race race) {
    return raceRepository.save(race);
}

@Override
public Optional<Race> findById(Integer id) {
    return raceRepository.findById(id);
    }
    
}
```

My repository :

```
    @Repository
public interface RaceRepository extends JpaRepository<Race, Integer> {

}
```

And I get this error :

> "message": "org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"

I think the nested object `stage` is saved first. So the `parent id` doesn't exist yet and it can't set `race_id` attribute.

Is there a way to save both `race` and `stage` in the same query ?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: Show us the controller and service and repository code relevant for your request, to reproduce the issue.

Comment: `stage` table doesn't have a `traceName` column, wtf?

Comment: Yes thank you @k-wasilewsk, I forgot it. I simplified my object to improve the readability of my question.

Comment: Ok, so your `Race` field has a `nullable = false` yet you don't include it in your json, hence the `ConstraintViolationException`...

Comment: If that's what you were looking for, I'll make it a proper answer.

Comment: @User - Upvote don't say Thanks No problem, I edited my publication

Comment: Yes  @k-wasilewski, but the fact is that this field can't be null. I need to have the Race parent on each Stage . And It's not possible to add it to the Json because it doesn't exists yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In JPA/Hibernate, you have to explicity set the bi-directioanl relatonship. When `race` object is created by jackson, it will have  list of `stage` objects. But `stage` objects will not have `race` object.

```
     @PostMapping(value = "save")
     public Race save(@RequestBody Race race) {
        System.out.println(race.toString());
        race.getStages().forEach(stage -> stage.setRace(race));
        return raceService.save(race);
     }
```

- Mark it as `Optional=false`

```
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "race_id".....)
    private Race race;
```

**Upate**

The second error you are getting is not because of hibernate.

- Either you are trying to print or debug the saved `race` object and `toString` object generated by Lombok goes into infinite recursion. To avoid that, do not make the `stages` part of the `toString` and `equals` method.
- Or infinite recursion is happening, when Jackson is translating the saved `race` to json. There are many ways to tell Jackson to avoid it but simplest you can do is

```
    @PostMapping(value = "save")
     public Race save(@RequestBody Race race) {
        System.out.println(race.toString());

        race.getStages().forEach(stage -> stage.setRace(race));
        Race saved = raceService.save(race);

        saved.getStages().forEach(stage -> stage.setRace(null));
        return saved;
     }
```

Comment: It's not working, I'm getting :
`Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null` because of infinite nested object loop

Comment: Well. I think the second error you are getting is not because of hibernate. See the updated answer

Comment: _'infinite recursion is happening, when Jackson is translating the saved race to json."_
 You are right @Kavithakaran Kanapathippillai, So I used @JsonIgnore on `race` attribute. Thank you for your time ! :)